# why headerFileName_H

Tags: c++

while I am creating a c++ header file, I declare the header file like;

```
/*--- Pencere.h ---*/
#ifndef PENCERE_H
#define PENCERE_H
```

I want to learn that why do I need to write underline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *need* to use the underline, it's just a convention to separate the header name and extension. You cannot use the literal `.` since that's not valid in an identifier so you replace it with an underscore which is valid.

The reason you actually do it is as an include guard. The entire contents of the file are something like:

```
#ifndef PENCERE_H
    #define PENCERE_H
    // Your stuff goes here.
#endif
```

so that, if you accidentally include it twice:

```
#include "pencere.h"
#include "pencere.h"
```

you won't get everything in it duplicated. The double inclusions are normally more subtle than that - for example, you may include `pax.h` and `diablo.h` in *your* code and `pax.h` also includes `diablo.h` for its purposes:

```
main.c:
    #include "pax.h"
    #include "diablo.h"
    // Other stuff

pax.h:
    #ifndef PAX_H
        #define PAX_H
        #include "diablo.h"
        // Other stuff
    #endif

diablo.h:
    #ifndef DIABLO_H
        #define DIABLO_H
        typedef int mytype;
    #endif
```

In this case, if the include guards weren't there you would try to compile the line `typedef int mytype;` *twice* in your program. Once for `main.c -> pax.h -> diablo.h` and again for `main.c -> diablo.h`.

With the include guards, the pre-processor symbol `DIABLO_H` is defined when `main.c` includes `diablo.h` so the `#define` and `typedef` are not processed.

This particular mapping of header files to `#define` names breaks down in the situation where you have `dir1/pax.h` and `dir2/pax.h` since they would both use `PAX_H`. In that case, you can use a scheme like `DIR1_PAX_H` and `DIR2_PAX_H` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The underline is not necessary, that's just a way to produce a string for the include guard that is unlikely to be produced anywhere else and cause hard to detect problems. Even more, you are free to select any symbol for the include guard as long as it will not be defined anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you can't `#define PENCERE.H`

You can define anything you want, but by using a format of using the filename, replacing `.` with `_` means you shouldn't clash #defines that guard importing the same header file twice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write the underline. All you need is a preprocessor symbol which isn't defined anywhere else. If you like (and/or if you have a Pascal background ;-}) you could just as well say

```
/*--- Pencere.h ---*/
#ifndef THE_PENCERE_HEADER_FILE_WAS_INCLUDED
#define THE_PENCERE_HEADER_FILE_WAS_INCLUDED
```

Comment: ..or `#ifndef _a176b657147fd4fef91379addff65aea`, if you put all kinds of stuff into the hash, chances are you won't get in trouble for having a util.h in different modules...